React Native functional state: 1st variable of the state undefined, 2nd variable of the state works. any solution?
In React Native, when using functional state with multiple variables, the first variable often shows undefined, while the second variable behaves as expected. Have you encountered this issue before? If so, how did you address it?
like this code

const[blood_pressure_count, SetBlood_pressure_count] = useState({
systolic:"",
diastolic:""
});

When I call blood_pressure_count.systolic, it shows undefined. For example, if I call it in an alert like Alert.alert("systolic-" + blood_pressure_count.systolic), it provides 'systolic-undefined' if no value is declared for systolic. However, it works fine with the second variable, diastolic, even if it has no value/declared in code.
need support, Please....
I'm attempting to save data to an SQLite database. However, when I save data from a state with multiple variables, where the state variables are initially empty, the first variable always saves as 'undefined', while the second variable works find and saves as empty/blank as there is no data.
even it is undefined if I call this from alert.


you need to change naming const [bloodPressureCount, setBloodPressureCount] = useState({}), 2) you probably somewhere use SetBloodPressureCount({ diastolic: something }) and that sets systolic to undefined

